# Local Notification Firing At Wrong Time

Tags: ios, nsdate, uilocalnotification

My local notification is firing about 2 hours too early.  The date that I set it to fire at shows 
2013-12-13 17:00:00 +0000

However, my phone shot me the notification at 15:00:00.  I want it to fire at the users' local time.  How can I adjust the date so that it fires at the users' local time zone...i.e. no matter where in the USA you are, it fires at 17:00:00?

Here is the journey of my NSDate.  I parse an XML file.  From the pubDate tag:

```
NSDate *articleDate = [NSDate dateFromInternetDateTimeString:articleDateString formatHint:DateFormatHintRFC822];
            NSString *articleImage = [item valueForChild:@"description"];
            NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
            [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
            [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

            NSString *dateofarticle = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:articleDate];
            NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateofarticle];
```

the NSDate *date gets added to the property from a custom class I have set up to store everything from each item of the XML.  So, the NSDate that is getting used for the notification is that.  When I set the notification, I make no adjustments to the NSDate.

From reminder UIActivity:

```
- (void)prepareWithActivityItems:(NSArray *)activityItems
{NSLog(@"works");
    Class cls = NSClassFromString(@"UILocalNotification");
    if (cls != nil) {
        NSString *message = [@"5 minutes until " stringByAppendingString:self.thetitle];
        UILocalNotification *notif = [[cls alloc] init];
       // NSLog(@"%@", self.thedate);
        NSDate *newDate = [self.thedate dateByAddingTimeInterval:-60*5];
        NSDateFormatter *formatter3 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

        [formatter3 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
        [formatter3 setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
        [formatter3 setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
        NSString *detailstext = [formatter3 stringFromDate:newDate];
        NSDate *othernewdate = [formatter3 dateFromString:detailstext];
        NSLog(@"other%@", othernewdate);
        notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];

        notif.fireDate = othernewdate;

        //NSLog(@"newdate%@", newDate);

        notif.alertBody = message;
        notif.alertAction = @"Ok";
        notif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;


                notif.repeatInterval = 0;


        NSDictionary *userDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:message
                                                             forKey:kRemindMeNotificationDataKey];
        notif.userInfo = userDict;

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
        [self.notifications addObject:notif];
        [notif release];

    }
    NSLog(@"Test");
    [self activityDidFinish:YES];
    }
- (void)showReminder:(NSString *)text {

    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Reminder"
                                                        message:text delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];
}
```

The  NSLog(@"other%@", othernewdate); shows as 2013/12/13 16:55:00 +0000 in the console.  I am in Central time zone.

UPDATE #2
In the area where a notification is scheduled I am running some tests.  I changed the XML pubDate to show -0600 after the time so it would stay Central time.  I run this code and logs.

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter3 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

        [formatter3 setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
        [formatter3 setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
        NSString *detailstext = [formatter3 stringFromDate:self.thedate];
        NSDate *othernewdate = [formatter3 dateFromString:detailstext];
        NSLog(@"details%@", detailstext);
        NSLog(@"other%@", othernewdate);
```

The string shows the correct date and time on this particular entry of:

details12/27/13, 3:00 PM

The NSDate shows this.  So, my question is this.  Since that time below is technically the same time...should the notification fire correctly?:

other2013-12-27 21:00:00 +0000

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to assign a valid timezone object to the local notification, i.e.:

```
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
```

If you need the notifications to fire at *your* timezone's 17:00, use `timeZoneWithName:` to create a timezone object of your timezone and set that as the local notification's timezone.

Comment: I want it to fire at 5 PM no matter where you are.  When it is 5 PM, the notification fires.  However, even setting the time zone to systemTimeZone hasn't worked for me.

Comment: How are you setting the date? If you print an `NSDate` object in the debugger, it shows in GMT timezone, so do not trust what it says there.

Comment: @user717452 - You don't show how you set the local notification time.

Comment: @user717452 Why are you doing so many transformations? Is that a category by `MWFeedParser`?

Comment: I'm just going off of what I am finding from the internet.  @HotLicks i set the notification time by `notif.fireDate = newDate;

        //NSLog(@"newdate%@", newDate);
        notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
`

Comment: @user717452 Your parsing code must not give you correct date/time.

Comment: 1) Edit your original question and insert the code that sets the notification.  2) Also insert example time values -- the character strings going in and the NSLog of the NSDate values coming out.  And disclose what your timezone is.

Comment: (And set the notification timezone BEFORE you set the fire date.)

Comment: Ok, original post has it up there now @HotLicks

Comment: @user717452 Notice that the log says the date is 16:55 in GMT. This means it is not set correctly. NSLog will always print dates in GMT, but it should be 10:55 for central US time.

Comment: How would 16:55 look in GMT to equal 16:55 for USA?

Comment: @user717452 Ah I made a mistake in my previous comment. 16:55 in US central would be 22:55 in GMT. CST is GMT-6.

Comment: Ok, the pubDate appears like this in the XML Fri, 27 Dec 2013 15:00:00.  If I changed it to Fri, 27 Dec 2013 15:00:00 -0600 would that make it fire at 15:00:00 Central time?

Comment: Ok @LeoNatan and ...check UPDATE #2 in OP for what is going on after changing the pubDate.